# How to use Bootstrap in Codeigniter?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter and couldn't find answer of where to add bootstrap library to local drive to be used in my project in latest version.

Answer (score 2):

Download [Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download)

and create `assets` folder outside application folder.

```
application
assets
    - css
        - bootstrap.min.css
        - bootstrap-theme.min.css
    - js 
        - bootstrap.min.js
system
index.php
```

---

**In config(`application/config/config.php`)**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/path/root/folder';
```

---

**In autoload(`application/config/autoload.php`)**

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

---

**In View(head)**

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: is this solution in official documentation of codeigniter?

Comment: when i inspect none of JS & CSS loading

Comment: you doing something wrong the. send image of your css directory